# jquery hover: mouseout not firing

Tags: jquery

Here is whats happening (Code Block Below):

1. I am working on a simple drop-down nav (based on nested Ul's).
2. The Main UL has an ID of #nav.
3. The hover-> mouseout function does **NOT** fire at all (all browsers)
4. After the 1st mouseover any **subsequent** mouseovers do **NOT** animate (i.e. slideDown) in Chrome 12.0.742.122, Safari (5.05), Opera (11.50), IE (9.0.8). In fact it **ONLY** seems to work in Firefox (5.0).
5. I've tested on **Windows** (7) only. No mac...yet.
6. The only way to get the animations to work again is to **refresh to the page**.
7. I'm learning this from a [Nettuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-tutorials/how-to-build-and-enhance-a-3-level-navigation-menu/) which was posted a little over a year ago, cant believe it's outdated already.
8. FYI: I'm calling jQuery and the script below at the BOTTOM of my html page.
9. Another FYI: I'm still **rather green**, so *clarity* in response would be very helpful

Any ideas?
Thanks In Advance,
sleeper

```
    var site = function(){
       this.navLI = $('#nav > li').children('ul').css('display','none').end();
       this.init();
    };

    site.prototype = {
       init: function(){
          this.setMenu();
       },

    // enables the slide down menu and adds support for ie6
        setMenu: function(){
           this.navLI.hover(function(){
               // mouseover
               $(this).find('> ul').stop(true, true).slideDown(250);
           }, function(){
               // mouseout
               $(this).find('> ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
           });
        }
    }

    new site();
```

Comment: cam you post what is rendered on the UI?  it would be nice if you can paste a screen shot of your UI as well as the HTML.  I'll give you a point for it.  [|:-)>--|<

Comment: It'd be great if you can post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: So let it be written, so let it be done! Give me a sec.

Comment: I THINK i did this fiddle correctly (fiddle is pretty cool, btw). http://jsfiddle.net/YCezK/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't need the `display: none` in your CSS for your `ul` elements.  Check out this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YCezK/3/) and you'll see the desired effect.

Comment: Wow. That was fast. One question: The Tut suggested that display none feature for those who have JavaScript turned off. So I commented out the display:none item and YEP it works. But then I turned off JavaScript and then Nope, It doesn't. the Sub UL's are showing. What about progressive enhancement/graceful degradation and all that?

Comment: Bump @vinceh on the JavaScript turned off/Nested UL's still showing thingy.

Comment: Oh well, guess there is no way around it. I suppose that in order to use this script, JavaScript MUST be on. Which kinda sucks.

Comment: Yes, sleeper.  The script won't work if you have JavaScript turned off..because..well..that's what it is, it's JavaScript.  The reason why it's there is because, like you said, of the case where someone does not have JavaScript turned on.  Refer to [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/YDaV9/3/).  But in order to keep that functionality there, it seems like you need to give up some fancy JavaScript animations.

Comment: Yup. It's cool. It's good know whats possible. Your right. Without the animations (and adding some cool CSS) I could get along...but I want it all...and I want it **now**! Ha ha.. :D Thanks for your very quick help @vinceh. Much appreciated.

Comment: Well, I guess this is quite old and nobody will ever read this but: you could just remove the display:none; (using .show() maybe) in the javascript file once the dom is ready and then continue. This way it will work with and without JS.